# Flutter image_picker 0.4.12+1 not returning from camera

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

I am using image_picker version 0.4.12+1 to take a picture from Camera on Android Emulator but the program never returns from `ImagePicker.pickImage` async call.

```
_takePicture() async{
    print("This is executed");
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    print("But is this never executed");
}
```

This [post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19103#issuecomment-412647536) on Github discusses the same issue and suggests a solution by modifying onMainActivity result. How can I do that? Or is there another solution that does not involve upgrading to AndroidX?

If it helps, the call will return successfully if I am using a different ImageSource.gallery instead of a camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using image picker version, 
**image_picker**: **^0.6.1+10** , this works.

```
Future _getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
}
```